# Function takes input as country name and sends output as a comma separated values of firstLetter of all the states in that particular country

Tags: javascript

Given below is a list of countries where we are supposed to complete
a function which takes input as country name and sends output as 
a comma separated values of firstLetter of all the states in that particular country

sample input - findCountryFunction("France")
output - "N,O,P,P"

```
  let countryData = {
  "France": ["Nouvelle-Aquitaine",
    "Occitanie",
    "Pays de la Loire",
    "Provence-Alpes-Côte d'Azur"
  ],
  "India": ["West Bengal",
    "Andhrapradesh",
    "Hariyana"
  ],
  "Bangladesh": ["Dhaka",
    "Khulna",
    "Barishal"
  ]
};




let findCountryFunction = (stateName)=>{
    for(let info in countryData){
        if(countryData[info] == stateName){
            console.log(countryData[info][0]);
        }

    }

};

findCountryFunction("France");
```

Comment: There is zero reason to have the for loop.  The stateName is a key in the object.

Comment: And `cityountryData` is an undefined variable.  Looks like this is a typo question.

Comment: Greetings! You seem to be new so here is a helpful article to read on how to create constructive questions [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

This is not valid `if(countryData[info] == stateName){` since info already has the property value. Check  how [for...in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) works.

You should have :

```js
function findCountryFunction(stateName) {
  let result = [];
  for (let info in countryData[stateName]) {
    result.push(countryData[stateName][info].charAt(0))

  }

  console.log(result.join());
}

let countryData = {
  "France": ["Nouvelle-Aquitaine",
    "Occitanie",
    "Pays de la Loire",
    "Provence-Alpes-Côte d'Azur"
  ],
  "India": ["West Bengal",
    "Andhrapradesh",
    "Hariyana"
  ],
  "Bangladesh": ["Dhaka",
    "Khulna",
    "Barishal"
  ]
};

findCountryFunction('France');
```

Comment: That's great. But we need to display first letter of each state and should be out of the array! i.e output = N, O, P, P  when we call findCountryFunction('France');

Comment: update snippet, You can store the value to an array and use the string as `yourArray.join()` to get the string.

Comment: `for (let info in countryData) {` is unnecessary and why did you switch to a `for...of` loop?

Comment: @Andreas, you are right, t was not needed, i just happened to have copied and try to keep my answer as per OP's snippet. Updated the code now. Even if was not needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can just do

```js
let countryData = {
  "France": ["Nouvelle-Aquitaine",
    "Occitanie",
    "Pays de la Loire",
    "Provence-Alpes-Côte d'Azur"
  ],
  "India": ["West Bengal",
    "Andhrapradesh",
    "Hariyana"
  ],
  "Bangladesh": ["Dhaka",
    "Khulna",
    "Barishal"
  ]
};
var country = countryData['France'];


for (idx in country) {
  var letter = country[idx][0];
  console.log(letter);
}
```

then iterate over the country variable to get the first letter of each element in the array